# Change class in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to change class in for loop when using the slider to fill an an number. The class stays as is when using the slider.

Input field `name="cijfer[]" id="ex'.$i.'` is filled correctly with the number in the slider.

Any suggestions to change the code to get this working?

Help is much appreciated.

[image]

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{ $i++;
    echo'

 <div class="container">

     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id_inh[]" name="id_inh[]" value="'.$row['id'].'">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">';
      if($i == 1) { echo '<label>Besproken punten</label>'; } echo'
      <textarea class="form-control" style="min-width: 100%" rows="4" id="optie[]" name="optie[]" onmouseover="validate()">'.$row['optie'].'</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">';
      if($i == 1) { echo '<label>Feedback tijdens functioneringsgesprek</label>'; } echo'
      <textarea class="form-control" style="min-width: 100%" rows="3" id="opmerking[]" name="opmerking[]" onmouseover="validate()">'.$row['opmerking'].'</textarea>

      <input id="ex'.$i.'" type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="" class="slider_darko"/>
      <span id="ex'.$i.'CurrentSliderValLabel"> Cijfer: <span id="ex'.$i.'SliderVal"></span> </span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" id="cijfer_status[]"></span>
      <input name="cijfer[]" id="ex'.$i.'_slider_value" type="hidden" value="'.$row['cijfer'].'" onChange="calculatie(this, <?php echo $i ?>)" />
      <input name="i_val" id="i_val" type="hidden" value="'.$i.'" />

    </div>
</div>';
}

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculatie(selectVeld, nr)
{
    if (document.getElementsByName('cijfer').value == false)
    {
        document.getElementById('cijfer_status')[nr].className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('cijfer_status')[nr].className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should be able to access the input filed with `selectVeld` in your `calculatie` function, why are you using `document.getElementById` again if you already have the reference?

Comment: Also in generall I suggest using the JS console of your browser to test and debug stuff, e.g. is `document.getElementById('cijfer_status')[1].className` working in your console? you can also set it to other values to debug something quickly.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: I mean debug it yourself in your browser when you're displaying your website. Just press F12 (in most modern browsers) to open the debug view and you can run any JavaScript code in the console to test something (you should know that I guess).. I always use that :)

Comment: To help a little the line `document.getElementsByName('cijfer').value` cannot work I guess, since it returns a node list with **all** the matching nodes, you can't get the value of that collection.

Comment: you have error in php, html and javascript